# Using recursive promise loops with then

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, axios

There is a promise which returns a parameter for next loop. It is like:

```
promise1(){
    return axios.get('https://google.com').then(result=>{
     if (result == someValue){ // continues
       promise1();
     }
     else { //if result does not equal this value, just break this loop and return
       return "stackoverflow";
     }})}
```

In the end I want to call this promise and do something after `then`, it will be:

```
promise1().then(()=>{
//do something
})
```

However, `promise1` returns in first loop when i call this function like above. How can i make to wait till `else` block runs and returning "stackoverflow"? Actually, I understand why it returns in first loop, but how can i make that returning in specific condition ?

Comment: `return promise1();` in the recursive call

Comment: that was so fast :) That makes sense, you can rewrite as an answer, I will mark. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `promise1()` from the inside, it doesn't wait for it (as it is asynchronous). Instead, discards the promise returned from the internal call and resolves to  `undefined`.

To await that call as well, `return` it from the `then` handler (`then` will await it as if it were chained):

```js
function promise1() {
  return axios.get('https://google.com').then(result => {
    if (result !== '') { // continues
      return promise1();
    } else { //if result does not equal this value, just break this loop and return
      return "stackoverflow";
    }
  })
}
promise1().then(console.log, console.error)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```